# How to put "suscribe"button and "email input" in the same line?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I want to have the Input and suscribe button in the same line.

I've tryed to put  display: inline-block; in my css code as some users of stack overflow suggested, but it remains the same

```
    <!-- Mailchimp for WordPress v4.5.2 - https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/ -->
    <form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-195 mc4wp-form-theme mc4wp-form-theme-dark customize-unpreviewable" method="post" data-id="195" data-name="formu footer" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="mc4wp-form-fields">
        <p> 
            <input placeholder="Escribi tu email" required="">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="/* display: inline; */">
        </p>
    </div>
    <label style="display: none !important;">Leave this field empty if you're human: 
        <input type="text" name="_mc4wp_honeypot" value="" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off">
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" 
    <!-- / Mailchimp for WordPress Plugin -->

``

Now I have the suscribe button under the input email, but I want it to have it at the same line
```

Comment: One thing, never put CSS directly into HTML.

Comment: Please, reorder your code, indent it and close unclosed tags. It is unreadable.

Comment: I have tested your code on my dev site, see screenshot >> http://prntscr.com/o0m23q
Input box & subscribe button are in the same line, can you try by clear your cache?

Comment: Small correction 


  **<input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="display: inline">**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tidied up the code a bit for you and closed some missing tags and removed the Honeypot (that should be able to be inserted automatically via the Mailchimp plugin). The code above is extremely fragmented in places, so it's not totally clear what the main problem might be, but this is working:

https://jsfiddle.net/aoking/d14pnwsL/

```
<form id="mc4wp-form-1" class="mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-195 mc4wp-form-theme mc4wp-form-theme-dark customize-unpreviewable" method="post" data-id="195" data-name="formu footer">
  <div class="mc4wp-form-fields">
    <p>
      <input placeholder="Escribi tu email">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```